# How can I use INPUT as INCLUDE_PATH in Doxygen configuration?

Tags: doxygen

I have a C project with the subdirectories `lib1` and `lib2`.  `lib2` defines things depending on defines in `lib1`.  Therefore I set `INPUT = lib1 lib2`.  I don't want to repeat the folders for `INCLUDE_PATH` (because in reality these are a lot of folders).  I would like to reuse `INPUT` somehow.

The documentation of Doxygen states, that environment variables can be used with the syntax `$(xxx)`.  Therefore I tried `INCLUDE_PATH = $(INPUT)`, but this doesn't work, because `INPUT` is not an environment variable.

lib1/lib1.h

```
#ifndef LIB1_H
#define LIB1_H

#define LIB1_DEPENDENCY

#endif LIB1_H
```

lib2/lib2.h

```
#include "lib1.h"

#ifdef LIB1_DEPENDENCY
    //! @brief LIB1_DEPENDENCY was defined
    void lib2_function(void);
#else
    //! @brief LIB1_DEPENDENCY was NOT defined
    void lib2_function(void);
#endif
```

I would expect that in the documentation the brief description of `lib2_function()` is "LIB1_DEPENDENCY was defined".

I am using doxygen 1.8.15.

Comment: I think you should also have a look at the preprocessor settings of doxygen. Also always mention the version of doxygen used.

Comment: I added the doxygen version.  It is not clear to me, what you mean with the preprocessor settings.  Do you mean "ENABLE_PREPROCESSING", "MACRO_EXPANSION", ..., "SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS"?  If this is the case I can add further descriptions to the question.

Comment: I did mean those settings. Regarding the reuse of the INPUT settings in e.g. INCLUDE_PATH this is not possible.